# CPrintDialog::OnInitDialog does not get called every time

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc

I am using MyPrintDialog extended CPrintDialog.
The problem is:
OnInitDialog() method of MyPrintDialog does not get called on first time when the application try to open Print dialog.

I am trying to set the Printer name in the Print Dialog from the OnInitDialog() method.
Printer name is specified by the user in the application which I want to use for the Printing.

My OnInitDialog() method

```
CComboBox *wndCmbBox = (CComboBox *)GetDlgItem( IDC_PER_USER ); /*IDC_PER_USER which is ID of Prin Dialog combo */
if( wndCmbBox != NULL )
{
    wndCmbBox->SelectString( -1, PrinterName );
}
```

Or is their any way to set the user choice Printer name in the Print dialog..?

Please Explain.

**Edit**

Yes, by onInit()  I mean `OnInitDialog()`

I am using VS 2012 with Win7 32 bit. I am facing this issue only first call of `DoModel()`. Next consecutive `DoModel()` methods calls `OnInitDialog()`.
I have debug the issue and found something

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK AfxDlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM, LPARAM)
{
    if (message == WM_INITDIALOG)
    {
        // special case for WM_INITDIALOG
        CDialog* pDlg = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDialog, CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hWnd));
        if (pDlg != NULL)
            return pDlg->OnInitDialog();
        else
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above is the function of dlgcore.cpp. When issue is reproduced I observed that `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` returns `NULL`.

Please note that I have customized CPrintDialog and added one check box in it. I doubt if it is creating the issue.

Comment: Can you show when and how you create the modal dialog?

Comment: Also, if you use the supplied CPrintDialog instead of your customised version, does it also behave the same way? So, have you verified that your customisation is *not* to blame?

Comment: please find file at [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1cKJCC6FFs6SzBlMHhGTi16dzQ/edit?pli=1) location

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, although in your overridden OnInitDialog() you should call CPrintDialog::OnInitDialog() *first* rather than after your code. What happens if you just use CPrintDialog instead of CCustomPrintDlg?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you meant to say `OnInitDialog()` instead of `OnInit()`, then it's possible that your problem is explained by [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193272) although it seems to have been fixed after VC6 SP1.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But it didn't solved issue. Please see edit part for more details.

Comment: Your edit doesn't indicate that you tried what Roger suggested... What went wrong when you set up the message hook? Did you remember to statically link to MFC?

Comment: I have tried what Roger suggested. Even after setting hook and  statically link to MFC onInitDialog() is not called on first time.