# CMyPrintDialog::OnInitDialog() is not called in IE10

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc

I have a class named CMyPrintDialog derived from CPrintDialog of MFC. It's used as an ActiveX in IE, and the project is linked to MFC statically. It works well in IE8 for many years.
But the same binary of the project doesn't work well on IE10. The print dialog could pop up, but unfortunately its OnInitDialog is never called and causes problems.
The strange thing is that if I attach the VS debugger to IE, OnInitDialog will be called correctly and the customized print dialog works well.
Seems Microsoft has change something and causes the problem.

I found [a similar link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547352/cprintdialogoninitdialog-does-not-get-called-every-time) but it doesn't work.

Thanks a million for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by IE's new feature after IE9 - "Hang Resistance". We can avoid the issue by disabling the new feature: Set below value as 0, and close all IE windows. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\ Type: REG_DWORD Name: HangRecovery Value: 0

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your point exactly you want to say, Consider CPrintDialog crash your application with IE10.What is you need to do is,

Set up the message hook function, _AfxCommDlgProc(), in the constructor of your

CPrintDialog-derived class as shown below:

```
 // CMyPrintDialog is a CPrintDialog-derived class.
   CMyPrintDialog::CMyPrintDialog(DWORD dwFlags)
   : CPrintDialog(FALSE,dwFlags)
   {
      //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CMyPrintDialog)
      //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
      // MFCBUG: MFC 6.0 doesn't set the message hook!
      m_pd.Flags |= PD_ENABLEPRINTHOOK | PD_ENABLESETUPHOOK;
      // _AfxCommDlgProc is exported from static MFC libraries
      m_pd.lpfnPrintHook = _AfxCommDlgProc;
      m_pd.lpfnSetupHook = _AfxCommDlgProc;
   }
```

Comment: The code is same to yours in the constructor. My problem is not about crash. Actually the print dialog is popped up, but the message handle of the derived class for example, OnOk() is not called when I click the OK button. This makes the dialog doesn't behave right.

Comment: @Cesc are you sure on point that your message OnOK() has correct prototype as it is present in parent class. That is in your case you calling OnOK() means you owriting parent function.So prototype should be same else post some code related.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same. Just like what I mentioned, I build the dll and used it on IE8, all works well. But if I use the same dll on IE10, I got issues. I built the code by VS2012.

Comment: Can you please tell me value of #define _WIN32_IE in your project? Probably value may declared in stdafx.h

Comment: No such flag. BTW, my project is a MFC project created by VS.